# What happen underneath when I type 255.255.255.255 in web browser?

Tags: networking, firefox, ip, url, broadcast

I've learnt that 255.255.255.255 is broadcast address, then I'm curious what happen underneath if a web page element src is http://255.255.255.255 or I type 255.255.255.255 in url bar, will it broadcast some info to all local network computer of this request ?

[image]

Comment: Use Wireshark (or a similar tool) to find out.

Comment: @DanielB What filter should I apply to know it's from my web browser particular tab broadcast but not other places ?